# How to get data from a table with condition, that data cannot exist in other table

Tags: php, html, sql

I have 2 table, `perkakasan` and `peminjaman`. Both table have the same primary key which is `nosiri`. They have relationship and `perkakasan` is the primary key.These are the example of the table.

```
perkakasan
nosiri:SMKS001L, SMKS002L, SMKS001N

peminjaman
nosiri:SMKS001L, SMKS001N
```

I want to get data from table "perkakasan", with condition that data cannot exist in table "peminjaman", which in these case the data is SMKS002L. Please help me to do these, Any help is Apreciated :)

```
<?php
include 'capaian.php';
$test = "SELECT perkakasan.nosiri as nosiriperkakasan from perkakasan 
WHERE nosiri in ( SELECT nosiri FROM peminjaman WHERE nosiri != 'nosiriperkakasan' )";
$testcapai = mysqli_query($capaiDB, $test);

if($data=mysqli_fetch_array($testcapai)){
    do{$nosiri = $data['nosiriperkakasan'];

        echo "$nosiri";
    }while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($testcapai));
}else{
    echo "Gagal";
}

?>
```

The coding that I have tried is showing SMKS001L and SMKS001N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do left join and then filter these results, where there is no record in the second table.

`SELECT p1.* 
    FROM perkakasan p1 
    LEFT JOIN peminjaman p2 
       ON p1.nosiri=p2.nosiri
    WHERE p2.nosiri IS NULL`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am still new in this and havent even heard about left join before :), I really appreciate it, thanks again